# Filtering items of a nested list inside a dictionary based on whether they appear in another list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I have a nested list of dictionaries with another nested list of lists that looks something like this:

```
list_dicts =   [{'id': 1, 'text': 'his name is Roland Gefferson and he lives in New York and works in Manhattan', 
              'names':[['Roland Gefferson','PEOPLE'],['New York', 'LOCATION'], ['Manhattan',  'LOCATION']]}, {'id': 2, 
               'text': 'her name is Sarah Daniels and she lives in Spain and works in Madrid', 
              'names':[['Sarah Daniels','PEOPLE'],['Spain', 'LOCATION'], ['Madrid', 'LOCATION']]}]
```

I want to check whether the nested list under the key value of `names` has items that appear in the list below and if they don't, eliminate those list items. This is the list:

```
l = [Sarah Daniels, Roland Gefferson, Madrid, New York]
```

Desired output:

```
list_dicts = [{'id': 1, 'text': 'his name is Roland Gefferson and he lives in New York and works in Manhattan', 
               'names':[['Roland Gefferson','PEOPLE'],['New York', 'LOCATION']]}, {'id': 2, 
               'text': 'her name is Sarah Daniels and she lives in Spain and works in Madrid', 
               'names':[['Sarah Daniels','PEOPLE'],['Madrid', 'LOCATION']]}]
```

As you can see in the desired output, the items `['Spain', LOCATION']` and `['Manhattan', 'LOCATION']` have been removed as they don't appear in `l`.

My attempt code:

```
for d in list_dicts:
    for k,v in d.items(): 
        if k == 'names': 
            nes_list = v
            for item in nes_list:  
                if item not in l:
                     nes_list.remove(item)
```

Comment: the items in ```l``` are strings, forgot to add ' '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing unwanted entries in-place:

```
for d in list_dicts:
    for li in list(d["names"]):
        if not li[0] in l:
            d["names"].remove(li)
```

The copy `list(d["names"])` is created, so we can remove elements from the list safely while iterating.

Answer (score 2):

```
list_dicts = [{'id': 1, 'text': 'his name is Roland Gefferson and he lives in New York and works in Manhattan', 'names': [['Roland Gefferson', 'PEOPLE'], ['New York', 'LOCATION'], ['Manhattan', 'LOCATION']]}, 
              {'id': 2, 'text': 'her name is Sarah Daniels and she lives in Spain and works in Madrid', 'names': [['Sarah Daniels', 'PEOPLE'], ['Spain', 'LOCATION'], ['Madrid', 'LOCATION']]}
             ]

l = ['Sarah Daniels', 'Roland Gefferson', 'Madrid', 'New York']

out = [{'id': d['id'], 'text': d['text'], 'names': [[value, category] for value, category in d['names'] if value in l]} for d in list_dicts]
```